# How to Write JSON with Properties and SubProperties

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I need to write and send a JSON string to a web service.
I have to create a JSON as follows

```
{
    "SALES": [
        {
            "INDEX_NX": 1,
            "Audios": [
                {
                    "Name": "audio_file",
                    "Content": "string_base64",
                    "Extension": "WAV",
                    "Id": "1236585"
                }
            ],
            "Documents": [
                {
                    "Name": "proposal_based",
                    "Content": "string_base64",
                    "Extension": "PNG",
                    "Type_document": "PROPOSAL SIGNED"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "document_with_photo",
                    "Content": "string_base64",
                    "Extension": "PNG",
                    "Document_type": "CNH"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I do this with the newntonsoft class?

Comment: Technically thats not valid json -  you may have accidentally clipped trailing `]}`.  Otherwise, you need some classes that look like that to store the data.  I dont know what "tried with while" means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create respective classes to create JSON like this and then you can serialize objects of them to created this JSON.

I am not a VB.NET person so I wrote this in C# and converted to VB.NET code using some online tool.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class SalesContainer

   <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="SALES")>  _
   Public Property Sales As List(Of SalesClass)

End Class

Public Class SalesClass

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="INDEX_NX")>  _
    Public Property Index As Integer

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="Audios")>  _
    Public Property Audio As List(Of AudioClass)

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="Documents")>  _
    Public Property Documents As List(Of DocumntClass)

End Class

Public Class AudioClass

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Content As String

    Public Property Extension As String

    Public Property Id As Integer

End Class

Public Class DocumentClass

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Content As String

    Public Property Extension As String

    Public Property Document_type As String

    Public Property Type_Document As String

End Class
```

You can create JSON as following.

```
Imports System
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Module mainModule  
    Sub Main()  
        Dim salescontainer AS New SalesContainer
        salescontainer.Sales = New List(Of SalesClass)

        Dim sales As New SalesClass

        sales.Audio = New List(Of AudioClass)
        sales.Audio.Add(New AudioClass() With {.Id=1236585, .Name="audio_file", .Content="string_base64", .Extension="WAV"})

        sales.Documents = New List(Of DocumntClass)()
        sales.Documents.Add(New DocumntClass() With {.Name="proposal_based", .Content="string_base64", .Extension="PNG", .Type_Document="PROPOSAL SIGNED"})
        sales.Documents.Add(New DocumntClass() With {.Name="document_with_photo", .Content="string_base64", .Extension="PNG", .Document_type="CNH"})

        salescontainer.Sales.Add(sales)

        Dim serializerSettings As New JsonSerializerSettings
        serializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore

        Dim jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(salescontainer, serializerSettings)
        Console.WriteLine(jsonData)

    End Sub  
End Module
```

Comment: This should not be accepted as the answer. The code is broken due to a bad conversion and needs a lot of work to fix.  Hint, there is no `var` in VB. If you'd have pasted that mess in a simple VB console app yould have seen how bad it is.

Comment: @MrGadget I apologise for the faulty code. Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected the code in the answer. I hope this is now in order. I will happy to correct if still something is not right.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015 (and perhaps prior versions) you can start a new class code file, and with that open and well-formed JSON in your clipboard, the `Edit` menu has `Paste Special` > `Paste JSON as Classes`, which does a decent job (but not quite perfect). From that, we get the classes below, and a little module to generate the JSON from those classes.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Docs As New List(Of Document)
        Docs.Add(New Document With {
            .Name = "proposal_based",
            .Content = "string_base64",
            .Extension = "PNG",
            .Type_document = "PROPOSAL"})
        Docs.Add(New Document With {
            .Name = "document_with_photo",
            .Content = "string_base64",
            .Extension = "PNG",
            .Document_type = "CNH"})

        Dim Rootobject As New Rootobject
        With Rootobject
            .SALES = {New SALE With {
                .INDEX_NX = 1,
                .Audios = {New Audio With {
                    .Name = "audio_file",
                    .Content = "string_base64",
                    .Extension = "WAV",
                    .Id = "1236585"}},
                .Documents = Docs.ToArray}}
        End With

        Dim Settings As New JsonSerializerSettings
        Settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        Settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore

        Dim JSON As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Rootobject, Settings)

        Debug.Print(JSON)
        ' Submit JSON to your web service
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property SALES As SALE()
End Class

Public Class SALE
    Public Property INDEX_NX As Integer
    Public Property Audios As Audio()
    Public Property Documents As Document()
End Class

Public Class Audio
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Content As String
    Public Property Extension As String
    Public Property Id As String
End Class

Public Class Document
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Content As String
    Public Property Extension As String
    Public Property Type_document As String
    Public Property Document_type As String
End Class
```